# Word frequency hash table

Tags: java, hash

Ok, I have a project that requires me to have a dynamic hash table that counts the frequency of words in a file. I must use java, however, we are not allowed to use any built in data types or built in classes at all except standard arrays. Also, I am not allowed to use any hash functions off the internet that are known to be fast. I have to make my own hash functions. Lastly, my instructor also wants my table to start as size "1" and double in size every time a new key is added.

My first idea was to sum the ASCII values of the letters composing a word and use that to make a hash function, but different words with the same letters will equal the same value.

How can I get started? Is the ASCII idea on the right track?

Comment: You could use the position of the letters in the words to improve the hash function.

Comment: its ok if multiple words create the same hash. a hash isn't supposed to be unique. in fact it can't be unique if the data being hashed is bigger than the hash. a hash determines which bucket a key is stored in, but then an equals check is performed to be sure

Comment: if you double the size of the array every time a new key is added, adding 32 keys will result in an array 4 billion entries wide :/ - perhaps they mean double in size every time it gets full

Answer (score 1):

A hash table isn't expected to have *in general* a one-to-one mapping between a value and a hash. A hash table is expected to have collisions. That is, the domain of the hash-function is expected to be larger than the range (i.e., the hash value). However, the general idea is that you come up with a hash function where the probability of collision is drastically small. If your hash-function is uniform, i.e., if you have it designed such that each possible hash-value has the same probability of being generated, then you can minimize collisions this way.

Getting a collision isn't the end of the world. That just means that you have to search the list of values for that hash. If your hashing function is good, overall your performance for lookup should still be O(1).

Generating hashing functions is a subject of its own, and there is no one answer. But a good place for you to start could be to work with the bitwise representations of the characters in the string, and perform some sort of convolution operations on them (rotate, shift, XOR) in series. You could perform these in some way based on some initial seed-value, and then use the output of the first step of hashing as a seed for the next step. This way you can end up magnifying the effects of your convolution.

For example, let's say you get the character `A`, which is `41` in hex, or `0100 0001` in binary. You could designate each bit to mean some operation (maybe bit 0 is a ROR when it is 0, and a ROL when it is 1; bit 1 is an OR when it is 0, and a XOR when it is 1, etc.). You could even decide how much convolution you want to do based on the value itself. For example, you could say that the lower nibble specifies how much right-rotation you will do, and the upper nibble specifies how much left rotation you will do. Then once you have the final value, you will use that as the seed for the next character. These are just some ideas. Use your imagination as see what you get!

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter how good your hash function is, you will always have collisions you need to resolve.

If you want to keep your approach by using the ASCII values of the you shouldn't just add the values this would lead to a lot collisions. You should work with the power of the values, for example for the word "Help" you just go like: 'H' * 256 + 'e' * 256 + 'l' * 256² + 'p' * 256³. Or in pseudocode:

```
int hash(String word, int hashSize)
    int res = 0
    int count = 0;
    for char c in word
        res += 'c' * 256^count
        count++
        count = count mod 5
    return res mod hashSize
```

Now you just have to write your own Hashtable:

```
class WordCounterMap
    Entry[] entrys = new Entry[1]

    void add(String s)
        int hash = hash(s, entrys.length)
        if(entrys[hash] == null{
            Entry[] temp = new Entry[entry.length * 2]
            for(Entry e : entrys){
                if(e != null)
                    int hash = hash(e.word, temp.length)
                    temp[hash] = e;
            entrys = temp;
            hash = hash(s, entrys.length)
        while(true)
            if(entrys[hash] != null)
                if(entrys[hash].word.equals(s))
                    entrys[hash].count++
                    break
            else
                entrys[hash] = new Entry(s)
            hash++
            hash = hash mod entrys.length

    int getCount(String s)
        int hash = hash(s, length)
        if(entrys[hash] == null)
            return 0
        while(true)
             if(entrys[hash].word.equals(s))
                 entrys[hash].count++
                 break
             hash++
             hash = hash mod entrys.length


class Entry
    int count
    String word

    Entry(String s)
        this.word = s
        count = 1
```